# I want all the amounts that have accumulated in the Label to be sum and show in another TextBox as a subtotal

Tags: vb.net

```
Const TaxRate As Decimal = 0.08, cappuccino As Decimal = 2.0, expresso As Decimal = 2.5, latte As Decimal = 1.75

Private Sub btncalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btncalculate.Click
    Dim price As Decimal, total As Decimal, cantidad As Integer

    cantidad = txtquantity.Text

    If cappuccinoRadiobtn.Checked Then
        price = cappuccino
        lblContenido.Text += "Cappuccino $2.00" + Environment.NewLine
    Else
        If ExpressoRadiobtn.Checked Then
            price = expresso
            lblContenido.Text += "Expresso   $2.50" + Environment.NewLine
        ElseIf LatteRadiobtn.Checked Then
            price = latte
            lblContenido.Text += "Latte     $1.75" + Environment.NewLine
        End If
    End If
    total = price * cantidad
    txtAmount.Text = total.ToString("C")

    lblRecibo.Text += txtAmount.Text + Environment.NewLine
End Sub
```

The question is: how can I sum the results that shows on Label called `lblRecibo` and show it as a subtotal on a subtotal TextBox?

Comment: There is no `+=` operator in vba. Use longhand, e.g. `a = a + b + c`

Comment: Controls are an awful place to store data.  Use a collection of some sort and just display the result to the user

Answer (score 0):

Are you using VB.net?
Why not use arrays?
Anyway, you just need to know the quantity or cantidad of each product.

```
'Label the index of elements in array (good practice)
Private Enum Product
    Cappuccino  = 0     
    Expresso    = 1
    Latte       = 2
End Enum

'Enter your maximum items here
Private Const PRODUCT_ITEMS As Integer = 3

Private Const PRODUCT_ITEMS_ARR As Integer = (PRODUCT_ITEMS - 1)

'Declare array for each product quantity 
Private Dim productQuantity_ARRAY(PRODUCT_ITEMS_ARR) As Integer

'Declare array for each product subtotal (actually without this you still can get each subtotal)
Private Dim productSubtotal_ARRAY(PRODUCT_ITEMS_ARR) As Decimal

'Initialize the arrays somewhere
Private Sub InitializeArrays()

    Dim i As Integer = 0

    For i = 0 To PRODUCT_ITEMS_ARR
        productQuantity_ARRAY(i) = 0
        productSubtotal_ARRAY(i) = 0.0
    Next   

End Sub

Private Sub btncalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btncalculate.Click
    Dim price As Decimal, total As Decimal, cantidad As Integer

    cantidad = txtquantity.Text

    If cappuccinoRadiobtn.Checked Then
        price = cappuccino
        productQuantity_ARRAY(Product.Cappuccino) += cantidad 
        'This line just updates the productSubtotal_ARRAY every click event
        productSubtotal_ARRAY(Product.Cappuccino) = cappuccino* productQuantity_ARRAY(Product.Cappuccino)
        lblContenido.Text += "Cappuccino $2.00" + Environment.NewLine

    Else
        If ExpressoRadiobtn.Checked Then
            price = expresso
            productQuantity_ARRAY(Product.Expresso) += cantidad 
            productSubtotal_ARRAY(Product.Expresso) = expresso* productQuantity_ARRAY(Product.Expresso)
            lblContenido.Text += "Expresso   $2.50" + Environment.NewLine


        ElseIf LatteRadiobtn.Checked Then
            price = latte
            productQuantity_ARRAY(Product.Latte) += cantidad 
            productSubtotal_ARRAY(Product.Latte) = latte * productQuantity_ARRAY(Product.Latte)
            lblContenido.Text += "Latte     $1.75" + Environment.NewLine

        End If
    End If
    total = price * cantidad
    txtAmount.Text = total.ToString("C")
```

And then multiply each product quantity with their corresponding prices or you can use the arrays for subtotal

```
Dim i As Integer
For i=0 To PRODUCT_ITEMS_ARR
    If(productSubtotal_ARRAY(i)>0.0)
        lblRecibo.Text += productSubtotal_ARRAY(i).ToString("C") + Environment.NewLine
    End If
Next
lblRecibo.Text += txtAmount.Text + Environment.NewLine
```

I don't know what really you are asking for. But you can try to tweak this thing out.